# Google Docs Problems in 12.04

Tags: internet

I am running Xubuntu 12.04.5 on my Toshiba Chromebook and I am, ironically, having problems with Google docs. Sometimes when I am using Google Docs and just typing stuff up, minding my own business, it switches to a random spot and starts placing the stuff I type there. I just have to delete it and retype it in the proper spot, but it is really annoying. Help please!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Use the 100% zoom setting in both Google Docs and the active tab in Firefox while typing the document. If you need to change to a different zoom setting than 100%, you should do it after you've finished typing the document.

Comment: From reading your other questions I found out that you have a Toshiba Chromebook 2 laptop. The Toshiba Chromebook 2 comes with either 2GB or 4GB RAM, which may also be relevant considering that you are using Crouton to run Ubuntu on top of Chrome OS.

Comment: I use one with 4GB and I run Firefox in Ubuntu, because Chrome uses up a little lot too much CPU for my liking.

Comment: @It'sWillem This isn't directly about the question, but it's a reply to your comment: [Chromebook Crouton RAM limit](http://askubuntu.com/questions/348383/chromebook-crouton-ram-limit).